# Use gdal installed with QGIS in Python Windows 7

Tags: python, gdal, installation, windows-7

On my Windows 7 PC, I installed QGIS 2.18 and gdal is part of this Installation.   How do I connect Python 3.6 to gdal?

Comment: Install it. You can get your gdal for python on Windows from gisinternals http://www.gisinternals.com/ Note you can have multiple GDAL installations (I have 4) but only one python install or you might experience problems.

Comment: Thank you, Michael. I decided to use the solution in my answer below, because there it was stated clearly, which installation fits to my version of python.

Answer (score -1):

I succeeded by following this:
https://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2016/04/13/installing-gdal-ogr-for-python-on-windows/